# align list style type bottom of the li content

Tags: html, css, list

```html
<ul dir="rtl" type="disc">
  <li>info@something.com</li>
  <li>career</li>
  <li>location</li>
</ul>
```

I want to align the list style type disc bottom of the `li` content now it is at the end of the content.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "bottom of the li content"? You want the bullet underneath the list item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `pseudo selector :after` and then you can `style` that much similar to `list-style:disc` as you want and then using bottom property align that at bottom of each li tag,

```css
li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ul dir="rtl" type="disc">
  <li>info@something.com</li>
  <li>career</li>
  <li>location</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

From **Ul** Removed **dir="rtl"** and just add this style **float: right;**.

So it's something like :

```
<ul type="disc" style="float:right">
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use pseudo-element "before", and position it how you want.

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In nulla, ipsam architecto. Pariatur quod officiis, facilis nisi optio cupiditate expedita, maxime soluta, beatae perspiciatis impedit sint eligendi possimus dolore quidem!</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In nulla, ipsam architecto. Pariatur quod officiis, facilis nisi optio cupiditate expedita, maxime soluta, beatae perspiciatis impedit sint eligendi possimus dolore quidem!</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<ul dir="rtl" type="disc" class="list">
                   <li>info@something.com</li>
                   <li>career</li>
                  <li >location</li>
                </ul>
```

CSS

```
.list{
  list-style-type:none;
}
.list > li{
  position: relative;
  margin:10px;

}
.list>li::after{
  content:"";
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  border-radius:50px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right:0px;;
  bottom:-10px;
  margin:auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/13k273z4/1/)